# Как сделать кеширование компонентов в react

Tags: база-данных, reactjs

Можно ли как-то грамотно реализовать следующий функционал?

На сайте имеется **меню**, которое можно изменять из **админки**. Следовательно, оно подгружается из **БД**.
Можно ли как-то сохранить контент от этого меню в **текстовый документ** на сервер (к примеру), читать от туда **html** и вставлять на сайт, чтобы **ускорить загрузку** сайта, не обращаясь на **сервер** лишний раз?

Comment: localstorage чем не угодил?

Comment: > There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Comment: можно, именно так, как говорите